# vuedraggable: register global component without import export

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vuejs3, vuedraggable

Is there a way to register vuedraggable as a global component without import export?

My setup looks like this now (simplified):

```
<div id="contentNavigation"></div>
<script src="/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/js/sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vuedraggable.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/vue-contentnavi.js"></script>
<script>
    navigation.mount('#contentNavigation');
</script>
```

In vue-contentnavi.js I try:

```
const navigation = Vue.createApp({
    template: `<nav>
                    <draggable><navilevel>...</navilevel></draggable>
               <nav>`,
    ....
})

navigation.component('navilevel', {
    template: `<li>
                    <draggable><navilevel>...</navilevel></draggable>`,
    ....
})
```

I tried to register draggable globally with

```
navigation.component('draggable', vuedraggable.draggable);
```

produces error "Failed to resolve component: draggable"

```
navigation.component('draggable', vuedraggable);
```

produces strange red output in frontend like  "X@http://localhost/.../js/vuedraggable.umd.min.js..."

I am sure my mistake is super stupid.

And I suppose I can use modules somehow by defining my main script "vue-contentnavi.js" type="module" and do an

```
import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
```

at the top but I would like to avoid modules.

Answer (score 0):

so yes, the error was stupid, the registration of a global component works well with this:

```
navigation.component('draggable', vuedraggable);
```

and the strange output in frontend is described in this [github-issue](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next/issues/57) at vuedraggable.

I thought I had a super big misconception because I (nearly) never use modules, webpack, npm or other tools(-chains) for frontend ...